# Python NLP library to decide whether a joke is offensive

Tags: nlp

Is there a python library that contains a method that by giving a joke decides whether the joke is offensive or not?

I found that repository [SemEval](https://github.com/akrahdan/SemEval2021/tree/0f1983f2aff60f9ccf01b69bf7ba57bf0148e6b0) but I assume that someone already made a user-friendly library to do so.

Comment: There might be systems which pretend to do this, but this is impossible in general: offensiveness is highly subjective so different people don't always agree whether something is offensive or not. Additionally it's the kind of highly semantic task where an automatic system cannot do really good: it will only reproduce the patterns found in the training data, and fail as soon as something is not similar enough to what it knows.

Comment: @Erwan I don't really care if the system only pretends to do this, I need it for a University project and I don't want to pay someone or do that manually

Comment: Afaik this kind of system would be either a research prototype (unlikely to be user friendly) or a commercial software (not free). Depending on the size of your data, it might actually be cheaper/faster to do it yourself or pay somebody. But if you don't care at all about whether the system actually works or not, you could just use any program which randomly predicts an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some pretrained models in [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/models?sort=downloads&search=offensive) which you can simply use them to detect if the sentence is offensive or not. For example you can use [twitter-roberta-base-offensive](https://huggingface.co/cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-offensive) model:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import softmax
import csv
import urllib.request

# Preprocess text (username and link placeholders)
def preprocess(text):
    new_text = []
    for t in text.split(" "):
        t = '@user' if t.startswith('@') and len(t) > 1 else t
        t = 'http' if t.startswith('http') else t
        new_text.append(t)
    return " ".join(new_text)

task='offensive'
MODEL = f"cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-{task}"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)

# download label mapping
labels=[]
mapping_link = f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cardiffnlp/tweeteval/main/datasets/{task}/mapping.txt"
with urllib.request.urlopen(mapping_link) as f:
    html = f.read().decode('utf-8').split("\n")
    csvreader = csv.reader(html, delimiter='\t')
labels = [row[1] for row in csvreader if len(row) > 1]

# PT
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL)
model.save_pretrained(MODEL)

text = "Good night "
text = preprocess(text)
encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
output = model(**encoded_input)
scores = output[0][0].detach().numpy()
scores = softmax(scores)

ranking = np.argsort(scores)
ranking = ranking[::-1]
for i in range(scores.shape[0]):
    l = labels[ranking[i]]
    s = scores[ranking[i]]
    print(f"{i+1}) {l} {np.round(float(s), 4)}")
```